# path loaded with query string giving 404 in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, url-routing

In my Next Application a url contains `query string`.

It works fine in local development sever.

But when it is getting deployed to production it is throwing `404` and application is redirected back to url.

For Example:
url => `www.domain.com?data=1`

**In Local** - Works Fine

**In Production** - Throws 404 and redirect to `www.domain.com`

And I've confirmed that `trainlingSlash` is set to `true` in my nextConfig.

It would be great if someone have any info regarding this.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this already? Where are you deploying?

Comment: yes @MuriloSchünke, in my app.js another developer has written code to overriting the routing. 

You can check this if this is the case with you.